# Laravel cleaner way of inserting data into a pivot table with triple table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

is this clean enough to insert directly the data to a pivot table with 3 foreign-key relationships,
my logic why I create this pivot table is to store the **[student_id,subject_id,mark_id, score]** then anytime I can edit and update the pivot table with the score of the student? I'm looking for an opinion on this if I am doing or approaching it the wrong way, please tell me, or any suggestion for better way of approach

**Controller:**

```
 public function Store( Request $request)
    {
        $subject=$request->subject_id;
        $student=$request->student_id;
        $mark=$request->mark_id;
        $data=[];

                 foreach($subject as $sb){
                    foreach($student as $st){
                        foreach($mark as $mk){
                            $data[]=StudentSubjectMark::create([
                            'subject_id'=>$sb,
                            'student_id'=>$st,
                            'mark_id'=>$mk
                        ]);
                    }}}  

                return $data;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "1",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "1",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "2",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "2",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "3",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "3",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 11
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "4",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 12
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "4",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 13
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "5",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 14
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "5",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 15
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "6",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 16
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "6",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 17
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "7",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 18
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "7",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "8",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 20
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "8",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 21
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "9",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 22
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "9",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 23
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "10",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 24
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "1",
    "student_id": "10",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 25
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "2",
    "student_id": "1",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 26
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "2",
    "student_id": "1",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 27
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "2",
    "student_id": "2",
    "mark_id": "1",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 28
  },
  {
    "subject_id": "2",
    "student_id": "2",
    "mark_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "created_at": "2020-02-06 01:31:35",
    "id": 29
  }
]
```

Comment: I find this question quite interesting and high quality, thou i am wondering why you input is structured by arrays, is it due to limitations of html forms or other?

Comment: cos i'm getting the data as checkbox[]  from the list of students, mark and subject